# facebook - getting context of user that clicks on a FB shared link

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way that of a link which an app shared to Facebook via open graph action to the news feed, which when a user/friend of the sharer clicks on it, it redirects to a landing page, where we could grab the information of the user (e.g. Facebook ID) just from the click itself? It might sound a bit magical, but anyone out there knows how?

Comment: please elaborate? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: deep linking is not at all related to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it´s not possible to just grab the user information just by his click, he MUST authorize your App for that. And you don´t get the real ID anyway, only an "App Scoped ID". Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: But given that the user ID of a Facebook user is rather 'public' isn't there a hack-ish workaround?

Comment: no, that would make the whole concept with the app scoped ids pointless. and scraping is not allowed on facebook. nevertheless, in that case it´s not at all possible.